# Traversing a vector in reverse and getting values of adjacent elements

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to traverse a vector in reverse order and check for consecutive presence of the digit 1. How can I prevent **going out of bounds** when checking for the first(last) element. 
Here is the code that I have written till now. Thanks in advance.

```
vector<int> bits;

for (vector<int>::reverse_iterator i = bits.rbegin();i != bits.rend(); ++i)  {
    int ctr = 0;
    auto be = bits.rbegin();
    auto prev = std::next(be, ctr);
    auto nx = std::next(be, ctr - 1);

    if ((*nx) == 1 && (*be) == 1 ) 
    {
            count_one++;    
    }
    ctr++;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to iterate backwards? Setting aside the bug, the shown example will give identical results whether iterated forwards or backwards.

Comment: Use `std::adjacent_find` in a loop.

Comment: *and check for consecutive presence* -- What is the "check" supposed to consist of?  If it's just to state that there are consecutive `1`'s somewhere, then as my comment stated, this is a one-line program using `std::adjacent_find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code by which I got my job done. Hope this helps someone.

```
std::vector<int>::iterator i = bits.begin();
if (bits.size() > 1){
    while (i < bits.end() - 1) {
        pr = std::next(i, 1);
        if (*i == 1 && *pr == 1) {
            count_one = count_one + 1;
        }
        i = i + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you'll only do this after checking that the vector `bits` is not empty, right?  (otherwise `bits.begin() + 1` is undefined behavior).